# How to know why a specific package version is being set in go.mod?

Tags: go, go-modules, go-packages

I have a Go repository with a `go.mod` currently requiring `k8s.io/client-go v11.0.1-0.20190409021438-1a26190bd76a+incompatible`.

I would like to bump the version of `k8s.io/client-go` used by my module but, when I change the version to be `v0.19.1` ([which exists](https://github.com/kubernetes/client-go/releases/tag/v0.19.1)) and then run `go mod tidy`, the version is set again to `k8s.io/client-go v11.0.1-0.20190409021438-1a26190bd76a+incompatible` with no explanation.

How to know why a specific package needs to be a specific version? I would like to know which of my requirement needs `k8s.io/client-go v11.0.1-0.20190409021438-1a26190bd76a+incompatible`.

Comment: Another dependency most likely requires that specific older version. Inspect your other dependencies & their corresponding `go.mod` contents.

Comment: This is not scalable when there are a high number of dependencies, I would expect a go command to give me this information instead of having to do it manually.

Comment: I had the same issue bumping from a "no-mod" to a "mod aware" package version. In my case, the major version was 5. The solution was to add /v5 to import, i.e., changing import `"github.com/foo/yyy"` to `import "github.com/foo/yyy/v5"`

Answer (score 3):

`go mod graph | grep v11.0.1-0.20190409021438-1a26190bd76a` should give you a starting point. You can work backwards from there.